# How to munge multi-line output into csv (via awk/sed Magic)?

Tags: awk, sed, grouping

I have been using the excellent (but somewhat rough) [Gatorgrouper](https://github.com/GatorIncubator/gatorgrouper) to make project groups for my classes based on various weighted heterogeneous and homogeneous criteria that students provide. The output of Gatorgrouper is

```
Group 1
Member 1
Member 2
Member 3

Group 2
Member 4
Member 5
Member 6
```

It would be extremely helpful for importing the output into several LMSs if Gatorgrouper had an option to output as csv. Something like:

```
Group 1,Member 1
Group 1,Member 2
Group 1,Member 3
Group 2,Member 4
Group 2,Member 5
Group 2,Member 6
```

But it doesn't. So far I've been semi-laboriously doing this in vim. Any Awk/Sed geniuses who can take the former and turn it into the latter? It doesn't have to be Awk or Sed, but standard command-line Unix tools, please.

Comment: Unless every group value really does start with the word "Group" and every member with "Member" then please [edit] your question to fix your sample input/output to contain more realistic sample values. Also add your attempt so solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) - setting an empty record separator and setting the field separator to a newline character:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="," } { for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) { print $1, $i } }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^Group/{g=$0}/^Member/{print g","$0}' dat.in
Group 1,Member 1
Group 1,Member 2
Group 1,Member 3
Group 2,Member 4
Group 2,Member 5
Group 2,Member 6
```

'splainings

snag a group if you see one.
output every member decorated with whatever group you happen to have.
ignore anything else

Comment: It seems unlikely that every group starts with the word "Group" and every member with the word "Member", despite the sample input/output the OP provided.

Comment: Ed you are of course correct in all things awk and here in the general case as well.  In practice we all borrow trouble at a rate we are comfortable with or can afford. I tend to work with domain experts who are truly not equipped to abstract properly, their abilities lie elsewhere. Forcing them to is generalize when the alternative is half a line of code is counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '!NF || !g{g=$0; next} {print g "," $0}' file

Group 1,Member 1
Group 1,Member 2
Group 1,Member 3
Group 2,Member 4
Group 2,Member 5
Group 2,Member 6
```